# How can i use the class that i wrote in other jsp file?

Tags: jsp, usebean

I'm a beginner in JSP. I wrote a package for userdata like this:

```
package user;
    public class UserData {
    String username;
    String email;
    int age;
    public void setUsername( String value )
    {
        username = value;
    }
    public void setEmail( String value )
    {
        email = value;
    }
    public void setAge( int value )
    {
        age = value;
    }
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

But when i try to do:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"/>
```

In another jsp file, I get an error like this:

```
Undefined type: user.UserData
```

How can I use my new class on the other jsp file?

Comment: do you want to import that class?

Comment: Actually i want to place the file UserData.class  in a folder named user under the classpath entry

Comment: Yeah. As user is the package your class file should go under it

Answer (score 1):

Skeleton of jsp useBean:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="id" class="bean's class" scope="bean's scope">
  <jsp:setProperty name="bean's id" property="property name"  
                value="value"/>
  <jsp:getProperty name="bean's id" property="property name"/>

 </jsp:useBean>
```